# dart how to specify class constructor outside the function?

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any way to specify class i need to build inside the function?

i wanted to create a custom flutter function to build different tooltips with common interface, but have no idea how to do this except throwing widget builder inside.
my idea is to do smth akin to the code example below:

```
abstract class T extends Widget {
  arguments...
  T(arguments..., Key key):super(key: key);
}

void  showSpecialBottomSheet<T extends Widget> (BuildContext context, arguments... ){
  showBottomSheet<void> (context: context, builder: (BuildContext context ) => T(arguments...));
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to help that tooltip guy and learn it by yourself too. That's nice. :)

Comment: what do you mean by different tooltips? class constructor outside of what function?    specify class inside of what function?

Comment: i want to specify a type in the button generic then build the widget inside based on that type. but i guess it won't work as static fields as well as constructors/factories are invisible for implementers in dart.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then this won't work because at runtime you don't know what type `T` exactly is, therefore you can't access any fields since you don't know which `T` has. Could be String, int, custom type - we don't know that at runtime. You might write something like: `abstract class BottomSheetData<T extends BaseData>` where `BaseData` is another class you wrote which has some generic stuff like `String title` and then access those data and still have the freedom to pass different implementations of `T`, if this makes sense

Comment: smth like that. i want to specify T's interface as every type T has the same constructor fields and it is a widget, so i could return it from the bottom sheet builder.

the closest thing i found is abstract class builder and i guess i will have to be content with it.

Comment: You can't directly invoke the constructor for a parameterized type in a generic.  You can, however, have callers supply a `T Function()` callback that does the work of constructing the object.

Comment: yeah, i done smth like this